# How to delay execution of a method for some miliseconds in Spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring

is there a best way for delaying the execution of a method when my application is based on Spring MVC and Hibernate? I only need to delay method A being executed for an hour when method B returns false.
I can only think of `Thread.sleep(3600000);`

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with Thread.sleep(3600000).

Comment: That's a bad idea. Why do you need to delay execution anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If your *method B* returns `false` enough times you might exhaust your thread pool and no request gets handled anymore.

Comment: The administrator of the application is going to perform api calls on fourSquare api that has limit 6000 calls per hour, so I need to implement something to hold the calls if a limit is reached and try again after one hour. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad design to me.

If I were you I'd take a look at libraries like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) and redesign the task to make proper use of schedulers.

It's a much better alternative than sleeping the current thread for one hour.